# Console showing different video client width

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

take a look at this:

https://jsfiddle.net/udr2m3xn/1/

This is the HTML

```
<video>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This is the JS

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');
var vw = video.clientWidth;

console.log('Client width: ' + vw);
console.dir(video);
```

The video is 320x176 px. However, the vw variable outputs 300 (it should be 320). But when you inspect the video properties you can see that it says that the client width is 320.

[image: Chrome dev tools]

Is this a debug or I'm missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you wrap your console logs with a setTimeout() with a timeout of 1000ms what do you see?

Comment: @Nijikokun same https://jsfiddle.net/udr2m3xn/2/

Comment: Looks like I was off by a second, the issue is that the video must be _loaded_ into memory. Then you will see the correct video size :)

Comment: Check out my answer below for a deterministic way of getting the value every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wait for the videos metadata to be loaded before trying to access variables, using the `loadedmetadata` event is **deterministic** (meaning that given the same/different inputs the output doesn't exhibit different behaviors) whereas `setTimeout` is non-deterministic.

```
video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() { 
  console.log(video.clientWidth)
}, true)
```

I would suggest checking out the full list of [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) as there might be others that you will find useful!

Answer (score 0):

300 is the default width of the `<video>` element. The JS is executed before the video has the time to load, and set the proper width of the element. If you wrap your JS in `setTimeout()`, you'll see the correct width. See it live:

https://jsfiddle.net/udr2m3xn/3/